# App crashes in some countries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash

Our iPhone app, which is already on the App Store, works fine in some countries but crashes on other countries like Brazil, Mexico, etc. Is there any way by which I can simulate different countries in my simulator? I tried by changing location.
Getting crash log is difficult now.

Comment: Does it run at all in those countries, or crash upon launch?  I hear Rio is lovely this time of year :-).

Comment: Run the Settings app and go to General, then International. Change the Region Format to a country or language/country giving you an issue. If that doesn't help find the issue, also change the device's language to one appropriate for the problem countries.

Comment: @Patashu it does not have used unicode-string but it uses NSDate. what are the internationaliztion issue for date?

Comment: @danh It crash on launch. No other contry uses reported this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your testing device Go to Settings-Regions settings. Test with different locales. If you are having an app involving date formatter/date picker then these problems can arise.

Different Locales have different date formats. i.e may be 24 or 12hr depending upon on the region.

To set the locale of the date formatter here is the code.

```
NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[dateFormatter setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];
```